# Backbone cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined / not loading data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to fetch some data and display it with Backbone, but having no luck - I am not getting any errors, just no rendering (I built this really simple app using the todos example as a guide)

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Backbone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sps-container">
        <div id="main">
            <ul id="service-providers"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Templates -->

    <script type="text/template" id="sp-template">
      <div class="view">
        <label><%- name %></label>
      </div>
    </script>

</html>
```

app.js

```
$(function(){

    var ServiceProvider = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : function() {
            return {
                id : "",
                version : 1,
                name : ""
            };
        }
    });

    var ServiceProviderList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/web-admin/faces/Backbone/data.json',
        model : ServiceProvider
    });

    var myCollection = new ServiceProviderList();

    var ServiceProviderView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#service-providers"),
        tagName : "li",
                initialize : function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                    this.template = _.template($('#sp-template').html());
                    this.render();
                },
        render : function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    myCollection.fetch(function(c) {
        var v = new ServiceProviderView(c);
        main.html(v.render().el);
    });
        var SPView = new ServiceProviderView();
});
```

data.json

```
[
    {
        "id": "03c88b31-6719-4662-9ad8-64f247de13f0", 
        "version": 1, 
        "name": "Dino Tel"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "936690b4-6a4a-436d-abed-8ca316fbae22", 
        "version": 1, 
        "name": "Krusty Tel"
    }
]
```

I think it's not loading any data - there are no other errors though, and the json file is available. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is `this.main` declared? You aren't rendering anything in AppView.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't rendering anything in AppView. Also, the `ServiceProvider.lenght` check should use the instance `myCollection` and `ServiceProviderView` should be instantiated and added to the DOM in `AppView`.

**Update 1:**

I'm also not sure if you can use an element from the DOM as a template (Marionette allows such thing (with `layout`) but pure Backbone doesn't). You need to put the `AppView` into a template the same way you did with the `ServiceProviderView` and then call `$(body).html(appView.render().el)`.

**Update 2:**

There's one more issue (at least). `myCollection.fetch()` uses ajax and is thus asynchronous. It may not have the data fetched when you want to render it. Use it outside of the view.

```
var main = $(body);
myCollection.fetch(function(c) {
  var appView = new AppView(c);
  main.html(appView.render().el);
}
```

I see if I can put a working example together later, but adressing all the above should get you close.

Comment: I realised and set this.main to `$("#main")` in `initialize` on `AppView` (updated main post). I'm not sure how I should add `ServiceProviderView` to the DOM once instantiated (do I just instantiate it in the render function of AppView? or is there more to it?) - could you show me an example? Thanks

Comment: I would probably have only 1 view and use the template to iterate over each model. If you want to keep the. separate, you have to instantiate `ServiceProviderView` in `AppView`. Once you got this working I would suggest to use `Marionette.js` as it allows for sub views and more.

Comment: I've changed the structure a bit (only one view) and added some more info to the main post - thanks!

Comment: You instantiate `ServiceProviderView` twice and calling `render` in `initialize` is unnecessary.

Comment: If this helped to solve the problem, please accept the answer.